# Creating a table with PHP foreach function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table

I'm in a class called database programming. We got a data set and and put it into our servers. Now I have to use a jquery plugin to help visualize that data. I am using Graph Us plugin and trying to use the "Fill In" option.

My professor helped me create this function:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$country_query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM FemaleMaleRatioNew";
$result = mysqli_query($sql_link, $country_query);
$new_row = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $country = $row['Country']; 
    $query = sprintf("SELECT Year, Value FROM FemaleMaleRatioNew WHERE Country =     '%s'", $country);  
    $country_result = mysqli_query($sql_link, $query);
    while ($country_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_result) ) {
        $new_row[$country][] = array('year' => $country_row['Year'],
                            'value'=> $country_row['Value']
                            );

    }
}   

//print_r($new_row);


?>
```

the `print_r($new_row);` is only there to make sure it works and it does, it prints out the array when activated.

He then guided me to create the table like this:

```
    <body>  

    <table id="demo">

    <?php  foreach($new_row as $row):?> 




            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['year'];?></td>
                <td><?=$row['country'];?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>



    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Here we're "graphing up" only the cells with the "data" class
$('#demo td').graphup({
    // Define any options here
    colorMap: 'heatmap',
    painter: 'fill',
    // ...
});

});
</script>
</body>
```

What else do I need to do to get the table to work? I can't seem to figure it out. All it does is come out blank.

I'm sorry if this question isn't worded correctly or if I have not been clear on anything please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us the result of print_r($new_row)?

Comment: The formatting is really off. Would you mind reformatting your PHP according to this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html and just delete empty lines in the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple rows for each country in your $new_row variable. You have to iterate over countries first and then over the individual rows of data:

```
<?php  foreach($new_row as $country => $rows): ?>
  <?php  foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$country;?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Year'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Value'];?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Also please note that you need colon ':' not semicolon ';' after the `foreach` statement. This syntax (which is less known) is described here:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

If you want to display some sort of aggregate (for example sum) per country and you want to calculate it in PHP (as opposed to MySQL) you can do it like this:

```
<?php foreach($new_row as $country => $rows): 
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($rows as $row): 
    $sum += $row['Value'];
  endforeach;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$country;?></td>
            <td><?=$sum;?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: this works, but it doesnt display the information in the table how I want it....it just displays all of the countries in the table and then lists numbers 1-119

Comment: You haven't said how you wanted the information to be displayed. Do you want the sum of values per each country, average, product, standard deviation? You should be able to calculate all these things by adjusting inner loop.

Comment: I just want the values displayed for every year. I do not need the sum average or any other calculation of the values...just the values displayed and they will be added to a graph using the GraphUP Jquery Plugin

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/2h4ezag.png that is a picture of my code for a better understanding at what i'm looking at

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a single JOINed query to do this stuff, but you may not have gotten that in class yet. Since it's homework, I won't give you the flat-out answer, but here's the pseudo-code:

```
$countries = SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM YourTable;
while($country_row = fetch_row($countries)) {
   echo $country_row['Country'];
   echo <table>;
   $status = SELECT Year, Value FROM YourTable WHERE Country=$country_row['Country'];
   while($stats_row = fetch_row($status) {
        echo <tr><td>$stats_row['Year']</td><td>$stats_row['Value']}</td>
   }
   echo </table>
}
```

Comment: this would replace the first query i posted?

Comment: irrelevant: this is homework. you do not just give away the answer. the student must THINK for themselves.

Comment: I don't understand this? Would this replace my first query or do i use this as well as the one i'm already using?

Comment: @clo3o5: no, it just demonstrates the basic flow of what your code should do. you still have to provide the queries and actual code.

Comment: $countries = SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM YourTable;
while($country_row = fetch_row($countries)) {
   echo $country_row['Country'];                                           I got this part to work but the bottom part gives me an error and doesnt even load

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc, interesting approach. I usually do the query first then I loop through my arrays. Any particular reason why you should combine both at the same time?